# Printing out a colored play icon inline with text

Tags: symbols, arrows, inline

**Problem:**

I have been trying to figure out how to replicate a button without success. I want to achieve to replicate the following button in LaTex. Control buttons don't seem to be available in the comprehensive list of symbols.

**Button:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

To include a play icon in color green where the background is transparent, the round icon is green, and the arrow in black. The text "Run" should follow it.

Answer (score 7):

Simple option with `fontawesome` which provide icon `\faPlayCircle`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{black}{{\color{ForestGreen}\faPlayCircle}\ {\color{white}\sf Run}}
\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

Comment: I'm not using either XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: @kexxcream: You should state then that you can't use `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`. It's nevertheless a nice solution, apart from `\sf` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry about that, I'll keep it under consideration next time.

Comment: @kexxcream - Are you using `pdfLaTeX`?  If yes, update your `fontawesome` package and enjoy the solution.

Comment: From `fontawesome` manual:
This package works both with XƎ(LA)TEX and Lua(LA)TEX (using fontspec
to load the included original otf font), as well as pdf(LA)TEX (using an included
type1 conversion and character mapping of the font).

Comment: It seems that I already have the package fontawesome. Is there a tutorial for updating the package? I found it under `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome` and the updated file from `https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome`.

Comment: @kexxcream - With TeXLive, updates are delivered via `tlmgr`.  For 2014 (your version), it is frozen now.  I suggest you update your distro.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Since I asked about updating a package, I have to ask about the dist. What's the recommended way to update it?

Comment: @kexxcream - There is no real update.  You have to install tl2015.  Check [this document](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your icon using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{playgreen}{RGB}{58,193,62}

\newcommand\PlayButton{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=black,fill=black,thick,minimum width=3.7em,minimum height=3.2ex]
  (bframe) {};
\node[minimum size=2ex,circle,fill=playgreen,draw=none,anchor=west,label={0:\textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries Run}}]
  (bcircle) at ([xshift=0.3em]bframe.west) {};
\node[scale=0.8]
  at ([xshift=0.6pt]bcircle.center) {$\blacktriangleright$};    
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

Test text \PlayButton

\end{document}
```

With some minor changes to colors:

```
\newcommand\PlayButton{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=playgreen,fill=white,fill opacity=0,thick,minimum width=3.7em,minimum height=3.2ex]
  (bframe) {};
\node[minimum size=2ex,circle,fill=playgreen,draw=none,anchor=west,label={0:\textcolor{playgreen!70!black}{\sffamily\bfseries Run}}]
  (bcircle) at ([xshift=0.3em]bframe.west) {};
\node[scale=0.8]
  at ([xshift=0.6pt]bcircle.center) {$\blacktriangleright$};    
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

the result is

[image]